# Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Component`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, jsx

I have an Image component like this inside a `<TicketEntry/>` component:

`<Image style={styles.icon} source={require("app/common/img/DATS24.png")}/>`

When I run tests with `jest`, for `TicketList`, which uses `TicketEntry` components, I get an error like this:

[image]

Why is this the case since I see the image renders correctly when I run the app, and is there any way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Provide relative (from component location) path for image source in `require` tag.

Example:

```
<Image style={styles.icon} source={require("./app/common/img/DATS24.png")}/>
```

I'm assuming here that you have `app` directory on level of this component where you use `Image` tag.

If it's directory on top of current location then navigate there with `../../app/...` (as many levels app as needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Already tried this but the same error appears.

Comment: Are You sure that this file is there?

Comment: Yes, I already explained in my question that I see the image rendering correctly when I run the app.